# php select reords from multiple tables and compare results

Tags: php, mysql

This first statement selects all users a user is following and the second statement select all notes of the user and all the other users they are following, I am trying to combine two select statement:

`$get_user = $user_data['username']; $get_following = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM follows WHEREfollower= '$get_user' ")`

`$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  posts WHERE username = '$followe' OR username = '$get_user' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,5 ");`

I tried using the following code, but it only fetches a single user's when the user is user following more than person:

`$get_following = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM follows WHEREfollower= '$get_user' ");`

`$ffg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_following);`

`$ff = $ffg['follower'];`

`$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  posts WHERE username = '$ff' OR username = '$get_user' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,5 ");`

Pls kindly help fix this problem, thanks.

Comment: Change `WHEREfollower= '$get_user' "` to `WHERE follower= '$get_user' "` for nicer formating.

Comment: Use JOIN if there is a relation between those tables

Comment: @RaymondNijland pls how do i use that, any help pls?